How to disable Mac security settings
My story in a nutshell (why I want to do what I'm describing below): my /usr/bin/ld is broken and it's broken for a at least a year it seems. I have a friend of mine with a version of ld from 2023 which works fine. The problem is that I cannot install it because Mac doesn't allow me to edit files in /usr/bin. Just in case - I know what I want to do and I won't break my OS, I just need to do it.
So longs story short, after googling a lot about the problem the only solution proposed is to disable csrutil. Cool, but for some reason even after loginning into recovery mode I still can't update anything. Here is a couple of pictures:


Can anyone please help with this? Why it says that I need to be in recovery mode when I'm already within one? How can I c

Is this a work computer protected by some sort of additional security functions, or do you fully own and control this computer entirely on your own?

Have you tried running csrutil clear?

You can fix corrupted system binaries by re-installing macOS. You can re-install macOS without losing data or settings. https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac

csrutil is irrelevant as you are trying to modify the read-only part of macOS system volume.  Do as @Spiff says.

@music2myear this is my personal laptop I bought myself, from the apple store the day it was released, no second hand. I don't quite know what it could be

@Spiff do you think it's corrupted? It survived a bunch of updates so something could go wrong in there, but I think it works as expected but i can't find the way to disable the security thing

@Ramhound yes I did, but it didn't change anything.

@AlexZhukovskiy Don't you think your copy of /usr/bin/ld is corrupted? You said it's broken and you want to replace it with a copy that works from another system. Is there an alternative hypothesis besides "it's corrupted"? BTW, have you tried comparing hashes (md5 /usr/bin/ld on your system, vs on a working system)?

@Spiff I know for a fact that it's broken on an Apple side, I have 2 other people all upgrading to the latest XCode version and they all would start having issues with this. It's a bug on Apple side and I just wanted to use the older version which isn't bugged.
